# Tool to check YAML files for Kubernetes offline

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration

Is there some tool available that could tell me whether a K8s YAML configuration (to-be-supplied to `kubectl apply`) is valid for the target Kubernetes version without requiring a connection to a Kubernetes cluster?

One concrete use-case here would be to detect incompatibilities before actual deployment to a cluster, just because some already-deprecated label has been finally dropped in a newer Kubernetes version, e.g. as has happened for Helm and the switch to Kubernetes 1.16 (see [Helm init fails on Kubernetes 1.16.0](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6374)):

Dropped:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
```

New:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
```

I want to check these kind of incompatibilities within a CI system, so that I can reject it before even attempting to deploy it.

Answer (score 2):

just run below command to validate the syntax

```
kubectl create -f <yaml-file> --dry-run
```

In fact the dry-run option  is to validate the YAML syntax  and the object schema. You can grab the output into a variable and if there is no error then rerun the command without dry-run

Comment: I appreciate your answer and this is way I am currently doing it, but my main motivation was to check it without a connection to a cluster. I have clarified my question. Thank you for pointing me to this detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **kubeval**

https://kubeval.instrumenta.dev/

I don't think kubectl support client-side only validation yet (02/2022)